# Can I receive messages sent and received from another iphone on my account?

Tags: iphone, messages

Is there any way that I can make it to where I can receive the messages that are sent and received from another phone on my account? And will the other phone be notified somehow?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, with iMessage signed into the same Apple ID, messages both sent and received appear on both devices. This will not include any SMS, only iMessages. Go to Settings > Messages > Send & Receive to sign in with an Apple ID.

Comment: It includes SMS if you have the SMS relay feature enabled. I text from my iPad more than my iPhone.